# Unable to focus on GWT widget in FlexTable

Tags: java, gwt

I have a function in GWT code as below :

The table is populated dynamically, and I want to focus on the particular n'th row as per the input value.

```
private void focusOnRow(int pos)
{
    final TextBox txtIntPaid = (TextBox) display.getDataTable2().getFlexTable().getWidget(pos,4);
    System.out.println("Data"+txtIntPaid.getText()); \\ Data

    System.out.println("Table:"+ display.getDataTable().getFlexTable().getWidget(pos,4)); \\ prints HTML

    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute()
        {
         txtIntPaid.setFocus(true);
        } 
     });
}
```

Here I'm able to print the data from getText(), as well as the HTML of the created widget, but I'm unable to focus on the TextBox specifically. What am I missing here ?

Comment: it looks ok to me.  Sounds strange, but have you tried NOT using scheduleDeferred?  Also, could something else in your code be requesting focus also?

Comment: Yes I've tried it without scheduleDeferred as well, still it's not focusing. Also, nothing else is requesting focus as far as I know.

Comment: could the textbox be disabled or not editable at the time that focus is attempted?

Comment: Yes possible, but how is it able to print text from the box but unable to focus ?

Comment: the box can have text but be disabled or unfocusable i suppose

Comment: Try: `final TextBox txtIntPaid = TextBox.wrap(display.getDataTable2().getFlexTable().getWidget(pos, 4).getElement());
 `

Comment: @Adam I have found that it's a javascript widget, not a GWT one. I'm getting isAttached() as false. Is there a way to focus on a JS widget ? I couldn't find anything specific to this in the documentation

Comment: TextBox is a (gwt) Widget.  Did you insert it into the FlexTable?  I don't understand how isAttched() could be false